# Consistent use of CPU by Java Process

Tags: multithreading, cpu-usage

I am running a Java program which does a heavy load work and needs lots of memory and CPU attention.

I took the snapshot of task manager while that program was running and this is how it looks like

[image]

Clearly this program is making use of all 8 cores available on my machine but if you see the CPU usage graph, you can see dips in the CPU usage and these dips are consistent across all cores.

My question is, Is there some way of avoiding these dips? Can i make sure that all my cores are being used consistently without any dip and come to rest only after my program has finished?

Answer (score 0):

This looks so familiar. Obviously, your threads are blocking for some reason. Here are my suggestions:

- Check to see if you have any thread blocking (synchronization). Thread synchronization is easy to do wrong and can stop computation for extended periods of time.
- Make sure you aren't waiting on I/O (file, network, devices, etc). Often the default for network or other I/O is to block.
- Don't block on message passing or remote procedure calls.
- Use a more sophisticated profiler to get a better look. I use Intel VTune, but then I have access to it. There are other low-level profiling tools that are just as capable but more difficult to use.
- Check for other processes that might be using the system. I've had situations where that other process doesn't use the processor (blocks) but doesn't give the context up (doesn't swap out and allow another process to run).

When I say "don't block", I don't mean that you should poll. That's even worse as it consumes processing without doing anything useful. Restructure your algorithm to hide latency. Use a new algorithm that permits more latency hiding. Find alternate ways of thread synchronization that minimizes or eliminates blocking.

My two cents.